# Separate home directory and system files

Tags: partitioning, grub2, encrypted-partition

this is a quite tricky one, I suppose.

My current system is installed on a RAID 1 I created during the Ubuntu installation (i.e. /dev/md0). The swap partition is also on the RAID. My home directory is encrypted, the swap partition,too.

Now I have bought a SSD disk and would like to move the system files there for quicker startup and loading of applications.

I imagine the following procedure:
1. create a normal bootable partition and a swap partition on the SSD. Move the swap to the SSD (I have found instructions on that).
2. Boot with a live CD and move all the system files to the SSD.
3. move the home directory stuff up one directory level and add it to /etc/fstab so that the RAID is mounted as /home/

While all of that seems rather simple, I have to assume that I am unaware of a lot more problems that will come up.

Is this procedure the way to go?

One thing I am especially wondering about is the grub 2 configuration. Will it boot if I just move the files?
Furthermore, will the encrypted home directory be mounted correctly?

My alternative idea would be to move all home data to an external hard disk so that the RAID partition can be reduced to a size which fits on the SSD. Then I could copy essentially the whole system, move the home partition out again and copy the files back. However, this would require a lot of moving files via unencrypted devices, consuming time and making the whole encryption pointless.

I would appreciate a lot if somebody could give me some advice.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, i'm been doing this for many times:

1. Copy all the files
2. Correct /etc/fstab ( Especially the one for `/` )
3. Re-generate ramdisk with `update-initramfs`
4. launch `update-grub` ( you may have to do this in chroot )

But before any operation took place , i strongly suggest you to have a bootable CD or USB for system recovery. e.g fix grub2 with chroot

As long as the partition is correctly mounted , everything will be fine. For data copying you could use `rsync` or pack & extract with e.g tar

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have tried it but failed so far. One thing I discovered was that /dev, /sys and /proc have to be mounted onto the respective directory on the new boot partition so that they are available after chroot. Also it is necessary to make sure that grub is installed on that partition. I had to run grub-install to do it. The boot procedure goes through partly but reports a lot of "permission denied" although the file permissions are set correctly. So far I have no clue why this error shows up.